# Looking for a way to analyse results of a poll and compare them to expected results

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, ranking, polling

I will be conducting a poll on 5 to 10 people. I will have each of them score about 100 samples from 0 to 10 and then I will compare their answers with the expected values of those samples. I am treating the poll answers as the ground truth and I want to see if the expected values are the same. It will look something like this:

| person 1 | person 2 | person 3 | ... | expected value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 | 5 | ... | 4.4 |
| 5 | 6 | 8 | ... | 7.3 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I was thinking of using confidence intervals for each observation, but I'm not sure if the scales of the answers and the expected values will be the same (the people answering might set the bar for a 6 at something like a 10, because of the huge variance of the distribution, that I have scaled down to 0 - 10) and because of that I am leaning towards some kind of ranked approach, but then do I just take the means of answers and ignore their variance? I guess I could do a paired t-test for pairs of observations, but then again I'm not sure if this will fit here. Any ideas on a good way to approach this?

Comment: Your language initially distinguishes "their answers" (which would be the poll results) from "the expected values" (evidently something else altogether), but then it appears to ignore the poll in order to "see if the expected values are the same."  What is it you really want to do??

Comment: To clarify things. I have a machine learning model, which scores the difficulty of some tasks, but because of the nature of the problem, which is quite unique, I can't just take the models metrics and say that the model is good. They are of course a decent indicator, but I can't trust them completely, so to get a better evaluation of the model I want to conduct a poll and see how well the models predictions match the experts opinions.